# Android, NPE on customSpinner.getSelectedItem()

Tags: java, android

I'm working on an application that retrieve data from users: age, height, weigth and type of fitness activities.

I didn't find any solution about this problem

There is a **npe** on **getitemselected** on a custom spinner (*the fitness activities spinner*).

My goal is to see the item selected in the **spinner** and set a value called "percentuale" to make some calculation that I'll push to another activity in order to display it on a pie chart (here I've another problem but I'll deal with that later).

Here is the code:

```
Button next;
RadioGroup radioGender;
RadioButton male;
RadioButton female;
ArrayAdapter<String> adapterFitness;
ArrayAdapter<String> adapterHour;
Spinner spinnerFitness;
Spinner spinnerHour;
private RadioButton maleButton;
private double percentuale;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_welcome);
    initialize();

    setCustomSpinner(spinnerFitness, R.id.fitness, adapterFitness, R.layout.rowfitness, Fitness);
    // DIALOG
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setMessage(R.string.welcome_page).setTitle("Ciao!");

    builder.setPositiveButton("Avanti", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            dialog.cancel();
        }
    });

    AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
    dialog.show();

    final EditText textAge = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.age);
    final EditText textHeight = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.height);
    final EditText textWeight = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.weight);

    spinnerFitness.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            String item = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();

        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }});

    // ON CLICK LISTENER
    next.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(final View v) {
            if (textAge.getText().toString().length() == 0 || textAge.getText().toString().length() >= 3) {
                textAge.setError("L'età è un parametro fondamentale per impostare un dieta corretta");
            } else if (textHeight.getText().toString().length() == 0
                    || textHeight.getText().toString().length() >= 4) {
                textHeight.setError("L'altezza è un parametro fondamentale per impostare un dieta corretta");
            } else if (textWeight.getText().toString().length() == 0
                    || textWeight.getText().toString().length() >= 4) {
                textWeight.setError("Il peso è un parametro fondamentale per impostare un dieta corretta");
            } else {

                String spinVal = spinnerFitness.getSelectedItem().toString();
                switch (spinVal) {
                case "Atleta professionista":
                    percentuale = 88 / 100;

                case "Atleta agonista":
                    percentuale = 72 / 100;

                case "In forma":
                    percentuale = 56 / 100;

                case "Soggetto attivo":
                    percentuale = 40 / 100;

                case "Sedentario":
                    percentuale = 24 / 100;

                default:
                    percentuale = 1;
                }

                final Intent openDiary = new Intent(v.getContext(), Diary.class);
                final Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                final int age = Integer.parseInt(textAge.getText().toString());
                final double weight = Double.parseDouble(textWeight.getText().toString());
                final int height = Integer.parseInt(textHeight.getText().toString());
                // Per MASCHIO
                if (maleButton.isChecked()) {
                    double valueBas = 66.4730 + (13.7516 * weight) + (5.0033 * height) - (6.775 * age);
                    bundle.putDouble("valueBasale", valueBas);
                    bundle.putDouble("valueDCN", valueBas + percentuale * valueBas);
                    openDiary.putExtras(bundle);

                }

                // Per DONNA
                else {

                    double valueBas = 655.095 + (9.5634 * weight) + (1.8496 * height) - (4.6756 * age);
                    bundle.putDouble("valueBasale", valueBas);
                    bundle.putDouble("valueDCN", valueBas + percentuale * valueBas);
                    openDiary.putExtras(bundle);

                }

                startActivity(openDiary);

            }

        }

    });

}

// INITIALIZE
public void initialize() {
    next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonNext);
    maleButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.male);
    radioGender = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.gender);
    radioGender.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {

        }
    });

}

// SET SPINNER
public void setCustomSpinner(Spinner spinner, int id, ArrayAdapter<String> adapter, int layout, String[] list) {
    adapter = new MyCustomAdapter(this, layout, list);
    spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(id);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    spinner.setSelection(0);
}

public void setSpinner(Spinner spinner, int id, ArrayAdapter<String> adapter, int layout, String[] list) {
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, layout, list);
    spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(id);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    spinner.setSelection(0);
}

// SPINNERS ITEM
private static final String[] Fitness = new String[] { "Atleta professionista", "Atleta agonista", "In forma",
        "Soggetto attivo", "Sedentario" };

// CUSTOM ADAPTER

public class MyCustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    public MyCustomAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, String[] objects) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
    }

    @Override
    public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        return getCustomView(position, convertView, parent);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        return getCustomView(position, convertView, parent);
    }

    public View getCustomView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();

        View rowFitness = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rowfitness, parent, false);
        TextView labelFitness = (TextView) rowFitness.findViewById(R.id.atletaPro);

        labelFitness.setText(Fitness[position]);

        ImageView iconFitness = (ImageView) rowFitness.findViewById(R.id.iconFitness);

        if (Fitness[position] == "Atleta professionista") {
            iconFitness.setImageResource(R.drawable.clothing548);
        } else {
            iconFitness.setImageResource(R.drawable.flexions);
        }
        return rowFitness;
    }

}
```

stack trace

> 02-26 12:20:58.438: I/art(1807): Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
>   (already on) 02-26 12:21:05.377: D/OpenGLRenderer(1807): Render dirty
>   regions requested: true 02-26 12:21:05.379: D/(1807):
>   HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xa6e9e7c0, tid
>   1807 02-26 12:21:05.382: D/Atlas(1807): Validating map... 02-26
>   12:21:05.418: D/(1807): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection
>   established 0xa6e9e220, tid 1832 02-26 12:21:05.429:
>   I/OpenGLRenderer(1807): Initialized EGL, version 1.4 02-26
>   12:21:05.456: D/OpenGLRenderer(1807): Enabling debug mode 0 02-26
>   12:21:05.466: W/EGL_emulation(1807): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
>   02-26 12:21:05.466: W/OpenGLRenderer(1807): Failed to set
>   EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xa6e9a360, error=EGL_SUCCESS 02-26
>   12:21:09.784: W/EGL_emulation(1807): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
>   02-26 12:21:09.784: W/OpenGLRenderer(1807): Failed to set
>   EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xa6e9a360, error=EGL_SUCCESS 02-26
>   12:21:10.483: D/AndroidRuntime(1807): Shutting down VM 02-26
>   12:21:10.483: D/AndroidRuntime(1807): --------- beginning of crash
>
> 02-26 12:21:10.483: E/AndroidRuntime(1807): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   02-26 12:21:10.483: E/AndroidRuntime(1807): Process:
>   com.freealimentarycoach, PID: 1807 02-26 12:21:10.483:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(1807): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start
>   activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.freealimentarycoach/com.freealimentarycoach.Welcome}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
>   android.widget.Spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(android.widget.AdapterView$OnItemSelectedListener)'
>   on a null object reference 02-26 12:21:10.483: E/AndroidRuntime(1807):
>     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)
>   02-26 12:21:10.483: E/AndroidRuntime(1807):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
>   02-26 12:21:10.483: E/AndroidRuntime(1807):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144) 02-26
>   12:21:10.483: E/AndroidRuntime(1807):     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
>   02-26 12:21:10.483: E/AndroidRuntime(1807):   at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 02-26
>   12:21:10.483: E/AndroidRuntime(1807):     at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 02-26 12:21:10.483:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(1807):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221) 02-26
>   12:21:10.483: E/AndroidRuntime(1807):     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 02-26 12:21:10.483:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(1807):   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 02-26 12:21:10.483:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(1807):   at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
>   02-26 12:21:10.483: E/AndroidRuntime(1807):   at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694) 02-26
>   12:21:10.483: E/AndroidRuntime(1807): Caused by:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
>   android.widget.Spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(android.widget.AdapterView$OnItemSelectedListener)'
>   on a null object reference 02-26 12:21:10.483: E/AndroidRuntime(1807):
>     at com.freealimentarycoach.Welcome.onCreate(Welcome.java:62) 02-26
>   12:21:10.483: E/AndroidRuntime(1807):     at
>   android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5937) 02-26
>   12:21:10.483: E/AndroidRuntime(1807):     at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
>   02-26 12:21:10.483: E/AndroidRuntime(1807):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251)
>   02-26 12:21:10.483: E/AndroidRuntime(1807):   ... 10 more 02-26
>   12:21:12.246: I/Process(1807): Sending signal. PID: 1807 SIG: 9 02-26
>   12:21:12.504: W/art(2020): Suspending all threads took: 6.358ms 02-26
>   12:21:12.508: I/art(2020): Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC
>   freed 2102(126KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 0% free,
>   3MB/3MB, paused 7.968ms total 81.135ms 02-26 12:21:12.562:
>   D/OpenGLRenderer(2020): Render dirty regions requested: true 02-26
>   12:21:12.566: D/(2020): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection
>   established 0xae2dfd40, tid 2020 02-26 12:21:12.568: D/Atlas(2020):
>   Validating map... 02-26 12:21:12.574: D/AndroidRuntime(2020): Shutting
>   down VM 02-26 12:21:12.574: E/AndroidRuntime(2020): FATAL EXCEPTION:
>   main 02-26 12:21:12.574: E/AndroidRuntime(2020): Process:
>   com.freealimentarycoach, PID: 2020 02-26 12:21:12.574:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(2020): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start
>   activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.freealimentarycoach/com.freealimentarycoach.Welcome}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
>   android.widget.Spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(android.widget.AdapterView$OnItemSelectedListener)'
>   on a null object reference 02-26 12:21:12.574: E/AndroidRuntime(2020):
>     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)
>   02-26 12:21:12.574: E/AndroidRuntime(2020):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
>   02-26 12:21:12.574: E/AndroidRuntime(2020):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144) 02-26
>   12:21:12.574: E/AndroidRuntime(2020):     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
>   02-26 12:21:12.574: E/AndroidRuntime(2020):   at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 02-26
>   12:21:12.574: E/AndroidRuntime(2020):     at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 02-26 12:21:12.574:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(2020):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)

Comment: Post stacktrace to help others understand your issue

Comment: Can't you post your logcat stack trace?

Comment: You code doesn't even have `customSpinner.getItemSelected()` anywhere.

Comment: posted. I mean getSelectedItem(), not getItemSelected(), i got confused sorry

Comment: `Welcome.java:62` show us the code in that line. is it `String item = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();` ?

Comment: it is spinnerFitness.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {...}});

Comment: So this has nothing to do with spinnerFitness.getSelectedItem() you mentioned before. It looks like `spinnerFitness` object is null which means that you should check it probably with the debugger and some breakpoints

Comment: Solved, i've deleted setCustomSpinner and re-implemented the spinner in a clearly way! Thank you very much for your patience and speed of your answers and tfor pointing out the error itself , i wasn't able to see it